# about HDD not detecting when w10 installed in SSD

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, ssd

The existing OS is Windows 10 installed on SSD.and I have to install ubuntu on HDD. but HDD has not detected during partition it is a dell laptop

Comment: This usually happens with incompatible drive modes. "RAID" and "Intel RST" aren't supported (yet) in Linux. It needs to be AHCI but be aware you need to install AHCI support in Windows before changing modes, Windows won't boot otherwise.

Comment: can u tell me the complete steps